# Sort a Matrix using a Playa field inside the Matrix?

Tags: matrix, playa

I have a Matrix field with a Playa field in it. I'd like to sort the output of the Matrix using a text field from the Playa field. Is that possible?

Here's my code; I'd like to be able to sort by {former_member_info:people_n_family}:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="org_units" status="open" dynamic="yes" disable="{mcc_disable_mem_pag}" limit="1" require_entry="yes"}
{org_units_members_mtx var_prefix="former_members"}
        {former_members:org_units_member_name_rel var_prefix="former_member_info"}
        <tr>
            <td width="25%">{former_member_info:people_n_first} {former_member_info:people_n_family}</td>
            <td width="35%">{if '{former_members:org_units_member_title}' != ""}{former_members:org_units_member_title}{if:else}{former_member_info:people_title}{/if}</td>
            <td width="20%">{former_members:org_units_member_date_start format="%F %j, %Y"}</td>
            <td width="20%">{former_members:org_units_member_date_end format="%F %j, %Y"}</td>
        </tr>
        {/former_members:org_units_member_name_rel}
{/org_units_members_mtx}{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: What does {former_member_info:people_n_family} output as? https://docs.pixelandtonic.com/matrix/templating/field.html tells me that you can either have a fixed, ascending, descending, or random sort order

Comment: The code is part of a table that displays a list of people. The first column displays the first and last name. {former_member_info:people_n_family} outputs the last name. If I set the orderby parameter on the matrix tag to {org_units_member_name_rel} (which is the name of the Playa Matrix field) it orders the table by the Playa field's entry ID.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that this isn't currently possible. I had a Twitter conversation with Brad and Andris at Pixel and Tonic. Here's the conversation: https://twitter.com/BertBartBrett/status/583301880471773184